# Mapping string categories to numbers using pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array of data, each row represents a sample of data (5 samples) and each column represents a feature in the data (6 features for each sample)

I'm trying to quantify the number of states each column contains, then map them to a set of numbers. This should only be done if the column is **not currently numeric**.

This is easier to explain through example:

example input (Input is of type numpy.ndarray):

```
In = array([['x', 's', 3, 'k', 's', 'u'],
            ['x', 's', 2, 'n', 'n', 'g'],
            ['b', 's', 0, 'n', 'n', 'm'],
            ['k', 'y', 1, 'w', 'v', 'l'],
            ['x', 's', 2, 'o', 'c', 'l']], dtype=object)
```

For first column

```
curr_column = 0
colset = set()
for row in In:
    curr_element = row[curr_column]
    if curr_element not in colset:
        colset.add(curr_element)

#now colset = {'x', 'b', 'k'} so 3 possible states
collist = list(colset) #make it indexible
coldict = {}
for i in range(len(collist)):
    coldict[collist[i]] = i
```

This produces a dictionary, so that I can now recreate the original data as such:
(assuming coldict = {'x':0, 'b':1, 'k':2})

```
for i in range(len(In)): #loop over each row
    curr_element = In[i][curr_column] #get current element
    In[i][curr_column] = coldict[curr_element] #use it to find the numerical value
'''
now
In = array([[0, 's', 3, 'k', 's', 'u'],
            [0, 's', 2, 'n', 'n', 'g'],
            [1, 's', 0, 'n', 'n', 'm'],
            [2, 'y', 1, 'w', 'v', 'l'],
            [0, 's', 2, 'o', 'c', 'l']], dtype=object)
'''
```

Now repeat the process for every column.

I'm aware that I could speed this up by populating all the column dictionaries in one pass over the dataset, and then replacing values all in one loop as well. I left that out for clarity into the process.

This is horribly inefficient for space and time and takes a large amount of time on large data, in which ways could this algorithm be improved? Is there a mapping function in numpy or in pandas that could either accomplish this or aid me?

I considered something similar to

```
np.unique(Input, axis=1)
```

but I need this to be portable and not everyone has 1.13.0 developer version of numpy.

Also, how would I differentiate between columns that are numeric and ones that aren't to decide which columns I should apply this to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Categorical codes. See [Categorical section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  x  s  3  k  s  u
1  x  s  2  n  n  g
2  b  s  0  n  n  m

In [12]: for col in df.columns:
     ...:     df[col] = pd.Categorical(df[col], categories=df[col].unique()).codes

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  1  1  1
2  1  0  2  1  1  2
3  2  1  3  2  2  3
4  0  0  1  3  3  3
```

---

*I suspect there's a small change which would allow doing this without passing the categories explicitly (Note: pandas **does** guarantee that `.unique()` is in seen-order)*.

---

Note: To "differentiate between columns that are numeric and ones that aren't" you can use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) before iterating:

```
for col in df.select_dtypes(exclude=['int']).columns:
    ...
```

Comment: @Jeff for me it does it in the reverse order (or perhaps sorted order?), i.e. `2 2 1 0 2` in the first column of my (poorly copied) example.

Answer (score 23):

Pandas also has a map function that you can use. So, if for example you have this dictionary that maps the strings to codes:

```
codes = {'x':0, 'b':1, 'k':2}
```

You can use the *map* function to map the column in the pandas dataframe:

```
df[col] = df[col].map(codes)
```